Nodes Not Peering Despite Proper Setup
We launched a public network and have over 40 validators. But now, nodes that I’m personally remote accessing aren’t syncing or producing blocks. Here is a picture:

I performed the same actions each time. I added our same boot nodes, inserted all four keys we need in our chain. But still this. Any ideas?

I am curious if our boot nodes refresh their identifiers on their own? I’m not sure why this would be happening.
